# Wp-admin Redirection loop after moving to subdirectory

Tags: wp-admin, redirect

I've moved my Wordpress files from public_html to a subdirectory public_hmtl/my-site.com. 
I've changed my .htaccess in the public_html directory by

```
RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-site.com$ [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.my-site.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !my-site.com/
RewriteRule (.*) /my-site.com/$1 [L]
```

I've configured my database and wp-config.php too, to:

```
define('WP_HOME','https://www.my-site.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://www.my-site.com');
define('RELOCATE',true);
```

But when I want to login per wp-admin the path seems to be like:

```
wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.my-site.com%2Fmy-site.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
```

Do you have any idea?

Thanks

Kamil

Comment: Hey, I don't know why you are using .htaccess to . redirect, you would have done directly by changing the root folder from cPanel or apache config file.

Answer (score 0):

try this >>

step 1) on wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME','https://www.my-site.com/my-site.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://www.my-site.com');
define('RELOCATE',true);
```

now, on your /index.php
change this line: require( dirname( **FILE** ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
to

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/my-site.com/wp-blog-header.php' );
```